# Check if json contains a key in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I'm kinda new to react-native (and javascript in general). At the press of a button, I want to search a json api for a certain key (in this case a movie).

For example, heres the api https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json

Now on the press of a button, I want to check if the api contains a movie named "The Matrix".

The networking tutorial states that to fetch the json, you need the following method :

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    return responseJson.movies;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}

This returns a json object, but how would one query this object to check if it contains a movie named "The Matrix" for example?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do is use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for movies array in the json response and check for the value

```
   function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {

    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }

    //from where you are calling getMovies
    getMoviesFromApiAsync()
         .then(response => {
              var data = response.find((movie) => 
                   movie.title.toUpperCase().indexOf('THE MATRIX') > -1
              )
              console.log(data)
              if(data) {
                  console.log('found');
              }
         })
```

The other options are to use

[`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
 var data = response.some((movie) => movie.title.toUpperCase().indexOf('THE MATRIX') > -1)
```

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
 var data = response.filter((movie) => movie.title.toUpperCase().indexOf('THE MATRIX') > -1)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check for indexOf `> -1` ?

Comment: @RRikesh, Thanks for pointing that out, Just updated the answer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Cool, thanks a lot, it works :). One more question though. How do I get  it to show an alert displaying the json objects name when I click the button, instead of logging to the console? Alerts don't seem to work while in the method.

Comment: You would need the React Native Alert API https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html